# Calculate Amount of Days between Events - Android

Tags: java

I been looking thru the Android API and been looking for a way to calculate the number of days between the current date and a future date. I'm pretty new to android and i havent done java in a few years. Whats the easiest method to calculate this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198068/android-java-util-calendar-time-difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/) Days class for this:

```
Date oldEventDate = ...
Date newEventDate = ...
Days days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(oldEventDate), new DateTime(newEventDate));
int numberOfDays = p.getDays();
```