# Calculate Time Difference in Android

Tags: android

I am new in Android.I can't find any way to calculate the time difference.So please help me. I designed a simple application. In this program I took 3 EditTexts and in these EditText I want to input the login time and logout time then store these values in the Database, And in the 3rd EditText I want to display the difference between these two time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use standard Java api calls:

```
System.nanoTime()
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Also, check out these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352031/calculate-time-between-two-times-android) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198068/android-java-util-calendar-time-difference) for calculating time difference.

Comment: In addition to the above check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java)

Answer (score 9):

An easier approach -

```
Date interestingDate = new Date();
```

different in milliseconds between the actual current date and interestingDate by doing:

```
(new Date()).getTime() - interestingDate.getTime();
```

Check the referenced answer [in this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352031/calculate-time-between-two-times-android)