# How to get two time diffrences in android

Tags: java, android, time, android-studio

In my application there are two buttons. One will show start time and the second one will show the stop time when it's clicked. I need to get those two values, calculate the difference and multiply it by another value. Here is how i set value to one of the labels:

```
if (v == btnstart) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Work Start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Date d=new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    String currentDateTimeString = sdf.format(d);
    txtstart.setText(currentDateTimeString);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5127822/1178798

`long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); long end = System.currentTimeMillis(); long diff = end - start; DateTime dt = new DateTime(diff);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` for your calculation

```
if (v == btnstart) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Work Start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//    Date d=new Date();

//    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
//    String currentDateTimeString = sdf.format(d);
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    txtstart.setText(currentDateTimeString);
} else if (v == btnDone) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Work Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
doneTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
takenTime = doneTime - startTime;
txtDone.setText(takenTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you click on StartTime button get the time using `System.currentTimeMillis();` in a long variable since the time will be in milliseconds and similarly on StopTimer button u can do the same.
After that calculate the difference between the two time which you will get in milliseconds.
Just in case if you want to convert the milliseconds to seconds then divide the value by 1000.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Accept the answer if any of the solution worked for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long diff = end - start;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(diff);
```